# I’d like to be able to use SE without allowing all the Google tracking

Tags: feature-request, tracking

At the moment, I’m using a second, less restrictive Firefox profile to use SE. In my normal profile, I try to block everything from loading I didn’t really ask for. Sadly that breaks SE, as I can’t log in or *show more answers*. I think it would be possible to use scripts for all that which are not hosted by Google but by SE itself. Pity SE is following this ill fashion. I don’t think I’m going to be using the less restrictive profile every time I’d like to post on SE. I don’t think anyone will mind, on the other hand, but maybe this gives to think a bit. I bet I’m not the first one writing about this, still, should make it look more important.

Answer (score 4):

I use [uBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) (for a complicated reason: the ads on some sites take a while to load; this means that while I'm reaching for the flag link, its position will change, which hurts my ability to spam flag quickly). uBlock will block any Google Analytics shenanigans:

[image]

I do not experience any difficulties in using Stack Exchange *at all*.

Comment: I use uBlock and NoScript. No SE with that.

Comment: Can't you somehow make an exception in NoScript for Stack Exchange?

Comment: I looked into it but didn’t find anything SE related I could make an exception for. There are several domains being blocked, none of them looks like it’s from SE.

I’m using uBlock here in the less restrictive profile and SE still works, so it’s got to be NoScript.

Comment: Well, Stack Exchange gets JavaScript libraries (e.g. jQuery) from Google, to be precise from this domain: `ajax.googleapis.com`.

Comment: Jup, just saw it in Live HTTP Headers. No Google, no SE.

Comment: I use ublock, ghostery, and sometimes noscript. SE works perfectly for me.